# object orientated javascript - this.calcSomething is not a function

Tags: javascript

simple.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="simple.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
 <input type="button" id="click_on_me" value="Click me">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and simple.js

```js
class SimpleClass
{
 constructor()
 {
  this.buttoncalcElement = document.getElementById("click_on_me");
  this.buttoncalcElement.onclick = this.buttonClick_Handler;
 }

  buttonClick_Handler()
  {
  alert("hi babes");
  this.calcSomething();
 }

 
 calcSomething()
 {
  alert("bye babes");
 }
}



window.onload = function()
{
 simpleObject = new SimpleClass();
 simpleObject.calcSomething();
}
```

Loading the page, window.onload it gets into calcSomething and show me the alert, but when I click the button, it gets into the buttonClick_Handler, but executing this.calcSomething(); call, the console tells me

this.calcSomething is not a function. (In 'this.calcSomething()',  this.calcSomething' is undefined)

Anyone any idea?

Comment: I just tested on Plnkr, i dont see any error, your code works

Comment: @Leo That is bizarre, because it does *not*.